# How to fetching the data except undefined in react js

Tags: reactjs

I want to retrieve some data from a JSON file. But if the data is not available i am getting undefined. How to remove undefined data from my output.
Here is the sample code I have tried.

```
import React from 'react';
const DisplayDataAtHome = () => {
   const json_data=[{
    "merchant_id": 1,
    "medium_egg": 104,
    "small_egg": 100,
    "desi_egg": 110
  }, {
    "merchant_id": 2,
    "big_egg": 90,
    "medium_egg": 104,
    "desi_egg": 112
  }, {
    "merchant_id": 3,
    "big_egg": 95,
    "small_egg": 104,
    "medium_egg": 107
  }]
  console.log(json_data);
    return (
        <>
             <div className="outerDiv">
                 {
                     json_data.map((val, i)=>(
                         <>
                         {
                             typeof val.big_egg === "undefined" ? null: 
                             <div className="innerDiv">
                                    <p align="left">Big Egg</p>
                                    <p align="left">weight: 500gm.</p>
                                    <p align="left">{"₹"+val.big_egg+"/-"}<button>ADD</button></p>
                             </div>
                         }
                         {
                             typeof val.desi_egg === "undefined" ? null:
                             <div className="innerDiv">
                                    <p align="left">Small Egg</p>
                                    <p align="left">weight: 500gm.</p>
                                    <p align="left">{"₹"+val.small_egg+"/-"}<button>ADD</button></p>
                             </div>
                         }
                         {
                             typeof val.small_egg === "undefined" ? null: 
                             <div className="innerDiv">
                                    <p align="left">Desi Egg</p>
                                    <p align="left">weight: 500gm.</p>
                                    <p align="left">{"₹"+val.desi_egg+"/-"}<button>ADD</button></p>
                             </div>
                         }
                         
                         </>
                     ))
                 }
             </div>
                       </>
    )
}
export default DisplayDataAtHome;
```

My output should looks like ion one div I want to get all the data as one more div. Just forgot about div. I want to fetch the data, the undefined data should not come.
 `Here I am getting data as well as some undefined data also. But I want to remove the undefined data.`

1. Can anyone help me how to solve this problem

   ```
    Thanks in advanced.
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `&&` for this, so when first condition is undefined the && operation will not go further and will render nothing else it will render the second part.

```
json_data.map((val, i)=>(
                         <>
                         {
                             val['big_egg']  &&  
                             <div className="innerDiv">
                                    <p align="left">Big Egg</p>
                                    <p align="left">weight: 500gm.</p>
                                    <p align="left">{"₹"+val.big_egg+"/-"}<button>ADD</button></p>
                             </div>
                         }
                         {
                             val['desi_egg'] && 
                             <div className="innerDiv">
                                    <p align="left">Small Egg</p>
                                    <p align="left">weight: 500gm.</p>
                                    <p align="left">{"₹"+val.desi_egg+"/-"}<button>ADD</button></p>
                             </div>
                         }
                         {
                             val['small_egg'] &&  
                             <div className="innerDiv">
                                    <p align="left">Desi Egg</p>
                                    <p align="left">weight: 500gm.</p>
                                    <p align="left">{"₹"+val.small_egg+"/-"}<button>ADD</button></p>
                             </div>
                         }
                         
                         </>
                     ))
```

Comment: Still I am getting same issue.

Comment: Can you please check with JSON and test your code once again if you don't mind.

Comment: I updated the code, you need to use bracket notation `val['small_egg']` for this. Please check now

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is so helpful content.